# SQL - Need to select most recent entries from a table Group By? Distinct?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table with flight price details in it, see the simplified fields below:

```
FlightInfoId
AirportFrom
AirportTo
Price
DateTimeAdded
```

There are around 300 possible combinations of AirportFrom and AirportTo representing 300 different flight routes although there are millions of entries in the database so there are many entries for each flight route. What I want to do is pull out the latest entry for each of the 300 routes.  The latest entry can be deduced using the timestamp 'DateTimeAdded'.  I need a query which will return 300 rows showing :

```
AirportFrom, AirportTo, DateTimeAdded
```

DateTimeAdded is the most recent row of many for the route specified by AirportFrom and AirportTo

I hope his is clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: *"I need a query"* ... [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2012

Comment: The exact syntax will depend on your particular SQL flavor, but the basic idea is to use `GROUP BY` to collect all flights within the same route together, `ORDER BY` to push latest to the top, and `TOP`/`LIMIT`/`rownum` or similar to limit the output to just the 1st row for each group.

Comment: select distinct top 300 
airportFrom ,airportto,DateAdded
from Flightinfo
group by airportFrom,airportto
order by dateadded desc

Comment: @Damien Zasikowski - Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I think I need to Group By AirportFrom, AirportTo but I also need to pull out DateAdded but if I put this in the select list it says I need to have it in an aggregate function

Comment: Ok, what I think I have part of what I need here:

Comment: select top 1 AirportFrom,AirportTo,DateAdded 
 from FlightInfo
where AirportFrom='MAN' and AirportTo = 'MAD'
order by DateAdded desc

Comment: This pulls out what I need for the specific route of Manchester to Madrid.  Now I just need to modify it to do this for all possible routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is more or less database agnostic.

```
 select AirportFrom, AirportTo, Price
 from yourtable join
 (select AirportFrom af, AirportTo at, max(DateTimeAdded) LastUpdate
 from yourtable
 group by AirportFrom, AirportTo) temp on AirportFrom = af
 and AirportTo = at
 and DateTimeAdded = LastUpdate
```